# How can i create a function that returns a vector in R?

Tags: r

I want to create a function that returns its result as a vector, more specifically a function that returns the divisors of an input value and places them inside a vector.

```
divisors<-function(n){
  i <- 2
  c<-1

    x<-c()

      while(i <= n) {
        if(n%%i==0) {
        x[c]<-i  

        }
        i <- i + 1
        c<-c+1
        x


      }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need a `return` statement at the end of the function. You should also have `c <- c+1` be inside the `if` statement. Here's an improved version of your function:

```
divisors <- function(n) {
    i <- 2
    c <- 1
    x <- c()
    while(i <= n) {
        if(n %% i==0) {
            x[c] <- i
            c <- c+1
            }
        i <- i + 1
        }
    return (x)
    }
```

A faster version might look like this:

```
divisors <- function(n) {
    x <- n / (n-1):1
    x[round(x) == x]
    }
```

which doesn't use the `return` statement, but returns the last evaluated expression (namely `x[round(x) == x]`).